# How to invoke Blazor child component from parent component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a unique situation with migrating some old code to Blazor.  The following code would be contained in, for example, a "ComponentTest.razor" page. I want to access, via code in ComponentTest.razor, the `ParentComponent` its parameters as well as the `ChildComponent`'s and their parameters.  In this scenario, `ParentComponent` is invoked by the containing page "ComponentTest.razor" but the `ChildComponent`s are not and don't even seem to be reachable.

```
<ParentComponent PParam1="pValue1" PParam2="pValue2" PParam3="pValue3"> 
    <ChildComponent CParm1="cvalue1" CParm2="cvalue1"/>
    <ChildComponent CParm1="cvalue2" CParm2="cvalue2"/>
    <ChildComponent CParm1="cvalue3" CParm2="cvalue3"/>
    <ChildComponent CParm1="cvalue4" CParm2="cvalue4"/>
</ParentComponent>
```

Yes, normally `ChildComponent` would be placed in the ParentComponent.razor file and this works fine but that's not the scenario I have. There seems to be a way to use `RenderTreeBuilder` to access child components but I couldn't figure out how to invoke them so their `OnInitialized` executes and parameters are set.

Comment: Before I answer-- is the number of `ChildComponent` objects set to four, or does it come from a variable-length set of data?  I would treat those cases differently.  Do you really need to use internal markup to define your `ChildComponent` objects on this page?

Comment: The number of ChildComponent will vary.   I do need to use the internal markup to obtain the parameters specified on the ChildComponent.

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain the parameters?"  Where are the values coming from?  If they're coming from a data list, you should be passing the list to the parent, and cycling through the data there, rather than using markup like this.

Answer (score 3):

you need to have some changes in your setup to access child components in parent
Here is your complete code

ParentComponent.razor

```
<CascadingValue Value="@this" IsFixed="true">
    <div>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
```

The child components list to hold all child components

```
private List<ChildComponent> items = new();
```

This method will be called by child component each time its created in parent component

```
internal void Register(ChildComponent item)
{
    this.items.Add(item);               
}
```

This method will be called by child component each time child components is disposed

```
internal void Unregister(ChildComponent item)
{
    this.items.Remove(item);
}
```

Here is your Child component

This code gets access to its parent component

```
[CascadingParameter]
protected ParentComponent Context { get; set; }
```

When any child component is created, it register's itself in its parent component

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Context?.Register(this);
}
```

This is how child component is unregistered from parent component on dispose

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Context?.Unregister(this);
}
```

In the parent component
With above setup using List operations of your choice you can access all child component with their public functions and variables in parent component like

```
items.ForEach
items.Find
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Create a Service which you then inject into each component that requires the data
2. Use a page state component that you cascade - shown below.

Here's the state class:

`PageState`

```
public class PageState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? MyString { get; set; }
}
```

And the component:
`CascadingPageState`

```
<CascadingValue Value=this.State>
    @this.ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public PageState State {get; set;} = new PageState;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

And used in `Index`

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<CascadingPageState State=this.pageState>
    @*Any component can capture the cascade*@
    <Test />
</CascadingPageState>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />


@code {
    private PageState? pageState;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (this.pageState is not null)
            this.pageState.MyString = "Hello";
    }
}
```